# How to create bootable ISO image?

Tags: iso-image, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso)

I have a Windows XP ISO image, I extracted the ISO image and access the Windows setup manager wizard to configure an unattended setup answer text file.

After that, I went on to create the ISO image again. Then try running the ISO image, it gives me an error that "the operating system is not found". I have been trying various software to create the bootable ISO image (IMGBurn, nlite) but with no positive results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create modified Win XP bootable iso, then why not to use [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)? It allows you very easily to remove things you do not need (in my case for example gamepad drivers, stupid animated search dog and other ...) add the serial number, preconfigure many things and then create a new bootable ISO. Very comfortable and worked well for me.

[image]

Comment: +1 that a very good tool I like that. And its freeware.