# Is the ISO burning capability of Windows 7 bootable aware?

Tags: dvd, burning, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso)

Can I burn bootable dvds with Windows 7's burner? If not, what should I use?

Comment: rodey seems to have [addressed this](http://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso/137519#137519) last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISO burning function just burns whatever is in the ISO image to the disc; it doesn’t process the data contained in the image before writing it (hence, a corrupt image will result in a bad disc; Windows will not warn you or correct it before writing). Bootable images contain the boot-record (usually as floppy image) in the `.iso` file. So as long as the image contains the boot image, then the resulting disc should be bootable.

The burn-to-disc function (which has been available since XP) does not support bootable discs because it works on a file basis. You specify files to be burned, Windows copies them to a holding directory, then when you select the *write these files to disc* command, it compiles an image and burns that.

(Interestingly, even Microsoft’s own [MVPs don’t realize](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/w7itproinstall/thread/a390c948-649f-4625-ad89-023725ce5be9) that this is possible. I concur with JoelbX and avirk; [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) is a great—and free—program to burn both images and loose files/folders—without even having to first compiling an image! It has an easy to use interface, but also provides numerous configuration options for complete control.)

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by loose files/folders? Also just burned with AWS, I imagine it means average write speed and it said uncorrectable error with imgburn when on verify. This happened before, wonder if it's imgburn or my burner. Last time I remember burning it as 1X speed and it worked fine.

Comment: I mean that in the past, when you burned a bunch of files and folders to a disc, you had to first compile them into an image (e.g., `.iso`, `.bin/.cue`, etc.) This is due to the various [recording modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_recording_modes) and the limits of older hardware, but ImgBurn can burn a bunch of files to a disc, even in DAO format without first compiling an image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can of course. Just `.ISO` image should be bootable and it will be burn as bootable on DVD. But if you want a third party tool then [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) is a freeware.