# I want to try windows 8.1 free trial. Need to make disc from another computer

Tags: windows-8, disc

The computer I plan on putting windows 8.1 on only has windows-xp, and all messed up.

I was going to do that 90 day trial.Better than having something I can't use.

I've tried doing the install already a few times,really need some steps.

- How do I burn a disc from other computer?
- Do I need to wipe the hard drive first?

  If so how do I do that, because
  can't get internet or anything else on that one?

Comment: `I've tried doing the install already a few times,really need some steps.` What exactly happened?

Answer (score 0):

1) No need to wipe the computer, you will be able to do that during the setup

2) When you download the ISO file you burn it to a DVD on another computer using something like [nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/products/nero-burning-rom/free-trial-download.php), which will make the DVD bootable

3) You insert the newly booted DVD and select key that is specific to your BIOS to boot from it and follow the setup

Answer (score 0):

1) If the other computer has Windows 7 on it then you can burn a disc from Windows Explorer.

See this answer: https://superuser.com/a/137519/293112

2) You can do a custom install and wipe the computer during the Windows 8.x install.

Comment: Ill look at that some more.I've been hearing alot of bad stuff about people not being able to install right.

Comment: Maybe if they're attempting to simply install Windows 8 over exisiting OS, but we're talking about a custom install (i.e., a clean install).

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1.htm