# Wrong password after using registry backup

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, password-recovery

So before dealing with some software to repair my registry, I created a backup to it (simply by exporting the existing one), as I should have, and couple of days later, I decided to use my registry backup file, and that for some reason changed my password and even removed my PIN code...

I've also created a restore point in case I'll need one, but I guess it's not possible to access it without a password with windows 10.

I also have no windows CD because I received my laptop with an installed one so I can't use that method.

Is there any way to make a system restore/system reset without a password on windows 10? Even access to CMD would help.

Edit:

So I've decided to install new windows 10 since I wasn't able to gain access...neither using system restore worked.

Is there any way I can access the old windows using this 1?

Comment: Did you restore that backup because you had another problem, or did the problem start only after you restored?.  Exactly what "Registry Repair" software and "Registry Backup" software" did you use, and the specific links where you obtained them.  Unfortunately, most all "registry tools are known to do more damage than good, generally "solve" non-existent problems, and have become a huge vector for malware.  Dig into exactly what this software is, since there's a chance you may have more problems than you know.

Comment: I didn't use any software to backup my registry, i simply entered regedit and saved it.
After using the fix reg software, couple of days later, my pc started to stuck for some reason, so I thought that it might be the problem..
I ran the registry backup file that I created simply by clicking export on the regedit
After doing that, I rebooted my Pc, and the isn't the same, but the hint I had is the same @DaaBoss

Comment: Most of the programs suggested there are no longer available for download, but I'm trying the rest that are. Thanks! @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Comment: So I've decided to install new windows 10 since I wasn't able to gain access...neither using system restore worked.

Is there any way I can access the old windows using this 1?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem guys, thanks.
I managed to use my system restore point after using flash drive with windows 10 installation and it solved the problem, the only problem I gave now, is that I have 2 windows installed... I'll figure it out later, thanks guys for the effort

Comment: @Voxito Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't know I was allowed to answer my own questions.. looked kinda weird at first, I've posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

When I need to reset a forgotten or unknown password on a Microsoft Windows system, I use the [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You can download the software from [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor, Bootdisk / CD](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

You will need to create a bootable CD or USB flash drive from the [.iso image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file within the zip file you download and then boot the system from the CD or USB flash drive. Once you've done so, you can remove the password for any account on the system. Note that simply copying an executable file to a CD or flash drive as you might usually do to put files on disc/disk is not sufficient. You have to create bootable media so that you can boot from that media rather than booting the system into Windows. You can find instructions for creating a bootable CD in responses to another question posted on this site, [Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso).

Some systems will boot from a bootable CD or flash drive, if one is available, before booting from an internal drive. Others will attempt to boot from an internal drive first. If that is the case with your system, you may need to change a [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)/[UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) setting to configure the system to attempt first to boot from a CD or USB-attached device. To change the setting, if the system won't attempt to first boot from those media, you will need to hit a key or key combination when you restart the system before it boots into Windows to get to a setup menu. That key or key combination will vary depending on the BIOS manufacturer, but you should hopefully see a message appear on the screen before it boots into Windows informing you what key or key combination you would need to use to get to the system's setup menu.

There is an overview of the process for resetting an account's password at 
[Offline NT Password & Registry Editor, Walkthrough](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You can also find other guides for using the tool online, such as [Reset Windows 8.1 password with the free tool ntpasswd](https://4sysops.com/archives/reset-windows-8-1-password-with-the-free-tool-ntpasswd/) at the [4sysops](https://4sysops.com) site. The article explains how you can create a bootable disc, if you don't know how to do so. The author of the article, Michael Pietroforte, also has posted a list of other articles he has written for resetting a forgotten administrator password on a Windows system at [Reset Windows 7 / 8 administrator password](https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-reset-a-windows-vista-admin-password/)

I haven't yet needed to use the software on a Microsoft Windows 10 system, and the download page states "More or less tested from NT3.5 up to Windows 8.1, including the server versions like 2003, 2008 and 2012. Also 64 bit windows supported.", so I'm not certain it will work on a Windows 10 system, but I've used it for many cases where someone has forgotten a password for an administrator account on prior versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do need to create it as UEFI type, I know it since I've already tried another program to reset the password.
Anyway, while trying to create my boot usb flash drive, it gives me the next message 'When using UEFI Target Type, only EFI bootable ISO images are supported. Please select an EFI bootable ISO or set the target Type to BIOS. I'm using Rufus to create it BTW

Comment: you can it's entirely up to you if you want to boot using UEFI or legacy mode

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a bootable flash drive after downloading windows 10 from microsoft's website using Rufus to copy the ISO file.

After booting from the flash drive I managed to access the system restore app (which was protected by my password) and use the one I created before it all began.