# Create bootable Windows 7 ISO from non-bootable contents, bootdisk.img for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootable-media

I found some similar questions such as following:
[Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso)

But i need to make a **bootable DVD from win7** contents *(not XP or 98)* which are not bootable! I don't have legit code anymore to download from Microsoft and activate it and my laptop needs startup repair soon. 
**Where can i find bootdisk.img or Boot Information for windows 7**?!

Comment: "Where can i find bootdisk.img for windows 7?!" - Just [download](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) a Windows 7 ISO.  You still need a license code to install or activate Windows 7.  There is not a solution to that particular problem, outside of, using the key you own.

Comment: You can also use [Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-iso-download-tool) if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I knew there are there are lots of bootable OSs, and my desired windows 7, but i want to fix current contents to make it bootable!

Comment: Your problem cannot be fixed unless you download a `Windows 7 ISO`.  You indicated you were unable to do this.  I provided you the information, so you could solve your problem, by downloading the .ISO required to get the file you want.  "Where can i find bootdisk.img for windows 7?!"  - **Any Windows 7 .ISO**.  I am marking this as a duplicate of the question I linked to.

Comment: Dear @Ramhound , I think you didn't get the question.

Comment: The only part of your question that was clear, "Where can i find bootdisk.img", is solved by downloading an Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer! I downloaded and put proper boot information from here:
http://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/make-windows7-bootable.html
And appended the small boot information file to whole non-bootable ISO using ImgBurn, burned it and it worked!